# TypeError, Palindrome Testing (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I have made a program in Python 3, which tests whether a number is a palindrome. Obviously it is not done, but when I try to run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def testforpalin():
    i = 101
    lop = list(str(i))
    print(lop)
    len(lop)
    if lop[0] == lop[len-1]:
        print("hi")
testforpalin()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

I get that error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the line

```
if lop[0] == lop[len-1]:
```

you have `len-1` where `len` is the function that gives you the length of the string (hence the error - you are trying to do subtraction where one of the values is `len` which is a "builtin_function_or_method").  you probably mean `lop[len(lop)-1]` (which would work), but it would be simpler to do:

```
if lop[0] == lop[-1]:
```

because `[-1]` gives you the last element in a string or array (and `[-2]` gives you next-to-last, etc).